# Conditional test within pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone help me with a pandas question?  I have a timeseries dataframe such as this:

```
                       GOOG     AAPL
2010-12-09 16:00:00    591.50   551
2010-12-10 16:00:00    592.21   523
2010-12-13 16:00:00    594.62   578
2010-12-14 16:00:00    594.91   567
2010-12-15 16:00:00    590.30   577
...
```

I need to loop through each timestamp and test whether AAPL is > 570.  If it is, then I want to print the date and the price of AAPL for that entry.  Is this possible?

Comment: I've only used pandas once in the past, but if I'm recalling correctly it is built on top of numpy so can you use my_dataframe.where(my_dataframe[:,2]>570)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha I got it:

What you can do since it is built on top of numpy is this:

```py
my_dataframe[my_dataframe.AAPL > 570]
```

and you're almost done.
From here you have all the rows that correspond to AAPL > 570, now it's just printing out the values you need:

```py
valid_rows = my_dataframe[my_dataframe.AAPL > 570]
for row in valid_rows.to_records():
    print row[1],row[2]
```

The dataframe.where can be used for searching the entire frame.
I had forgotten that pandas made it extremely easy to reference columns.

Comment: I'm sure there may be a better way to do this, but this is what I could remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Also, I modify Ryan's code a bit    
    `for row in my_dataframe[my_dataframe.AAPL > 1].to_records():
        print row[0],row[2]`

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for any looping, one of the main benefits of `pandas` being built on `numpy` is it can easily operate on whole columns. It's as simple as:

```
df['AAPL'][df['AAPL'] > 570]
```

Output:

```
2010-12-13  16:00:00    578
2010-12-15  16:00:00    577
Name: AAPL, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is done more succinctly as ``df.loc[df['AAPL']>570,'AAPL']`` (and if you do assignment, you MUST do it this way

Comment: Also, what if only want to output the month-day and price?

Comment: @AlexLee: If you're having trouble with that, it might be a good idea to ask a new question along the lines of "Extracting month and day from datetime index", with some easily reproducible data. Stack Overflow works best with self-contained questions that solve a single problem.